# How to manage mail system using cpanel api in PHP

Tags: php, api, cpanel, webmail

I need to write PHP code, using the cpanel api to be able to manage emails.  So I will give clients a URL and login and they will be able to manage there own emails.

If any one have any idea please share this here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what google brought me to http://forums.cpanel.net/f42/xmlapi-php-class-111897.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment on my query but that is not what i'm looking for.
I want to give different unique url and login credentials to different users so that they can have access to their mails (usually users have to login into cpanel to access their mails through webmail).
Users can also compose and send mail through this customized system.

Comment: I really doubt you'll find a complete tutorial on how to make a web interface for accessing email services using cpanel's api....

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late, but doesn't visiting www.example.com/webmail (or webmail.example.com if configured that way) directly solve the problem?